# R: Elastic net prediction error calculation using cv.glm

Tags: r, machine-learning

```
library(glmnet)
library(boot)
data(iris)
x <- model.matrix(Sepal.Length~., iris)[,-1]
y <- iris$Sepal.Length
m <- cv.glmnet(x, y)
> cv.glm(x, m, K = 10)
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'double', 'numeric')"
```

or

```
bestLambda = m$lambda.min
m2 <- glmnet(x, y, family = "gaussian", lambda = bestLambda)
>cv.glm(x, m2, K = 10)


 Error in glmnet(x = x, y = y, family = "gaussian", lambda = bestLambda,  : 
  unused argument (data = c(3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6,
```

In reference to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156098/cross-validating-lasso-regression-in-r) question, I'm trying to obtain the K-fold cross-validated prediction error of my Elastic net model using `cv.glm`, however, I can't seem to do so due to the error. I'm not quite sure if the `cv.glm` function can be used to calculate the prediction error of a class `cv.glm` or `glmnet` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing up `glm` with `glmnet` (elastic net, with lasso & ridge penalties). `cv.glm` expects a `glm` model, not a `glmnet` model.

Try either of the following:

1. Use `glmnet` to compute k-fold cross-validation errors with `cv.glmnet` like the following:

   ```
   library(glmnet)
   library(boot)
   data(iris)
   x <- model.matrix(Sepal.Length~., iris)[,-1]
   y <- iris$Sepal.Length
   m <- cv.glmnet(x, y, nfolds=10)
   m$lambda.min
   #[1] 0.0003839539
   m$lambda.1se
   #[1] 0.009078549
   plot(m$lambda, m$cvm,type='l', xlab=expression(lambda), ylab='CV errors', main=expression(paste('CV error for different ', lambda)))
   lines(m$lambda, m$cvup, col='red')
   lines(m$lambda, m$cvlo, col='red')
   ```

   [image]

**[EDITED]**

prediction error on the training dataset:

```
mean((y-predict(m, newx=x))^2)
# [1] 0.1037433
```

2. Fit a `glm` model and use `cv.glm` to compute the cross-validation error delta (without regularization). As per the documentation of `cv.glm`:

> delta:    A vector of length two. The first component is the raw
>   cross-validation estimate of prediction error. The second component is
>   the adjusted cross-validation estimate. The adjustment is designed to
>   compensate for the bias introduced by not using leave-one-out
>   cross-validation.

```
df <- cbind.data.frame(x, y)
m <- glm(y~., df, family='gaussian')
cv.glm(df, m, K = 10)$delta 
# [1] 0.09992177 0.09940190
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems like `m$cvm` gives me the cross-validated MSE, not necessarily the prediction errors. How would you calculate the cross-validated prediction errors of a elastic net model?

Comment: if you want prediction error you can try `mean((y-predict(m, newx=x))^2)`